# How to run two copies of xampp at the same time?

Tags: xampp

For some reason, I need to run two copies of xampp at the same time. I read many tutorials on the internet but they are end up tell me to turn off current xampp if I need to run the other. 
Is is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run two xampp's at the same time using different ports. I think that could be possible. Just edit the configuration for xampp change the ports on the 2nd one and wolla!

Comment: Thank you, it works! However, after changing port to 81, I have to type myvirtualdomain:81 to access my site in the second xampp, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Hmm. Well have you heard about vhosts?